# Correct llvm target triple for iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, code-generation, llvm

I have written a small piece of code to generate an LLVM module containing a few global variables. I am converting the module to LLVM assembly code using the LLVM assembler and then to native binary before linking it to other libraries to produce the final binary which is an iPhone app. Everything work fine when I build for the device but when I build for the simulator I get the following error when converting from LLVM assembly to machine code:

```
file.asm:1:Unknown pseudo-op: .syntax
file.asm:1:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 117 (u).
```

I am suspecting that the target triple is incorrect for the simulator architecture. I am using `armv6-apple-darwin9` for device and `i386-apple-darwin10` for simulator. Can someone point out the correct target triple for simulator? Any other tip is equally welcome. The simulator is running on a "10.7 Darwin i386" machine (or so `uname -a` tells me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're feeding the arm assembler code the i386 assembler (".syntax unified" is ARM-only thing). So, yes, you should generate the code for x86. Most probably - for i386-apple-darwin10. Not sure about the simulator though.

Comment: I tried specifying 'i366-apple-darwin10' but the assembly file produced still has '.syntax unifies'. In fact, that string does not go away for any combination of i386, i686 and darwin9, darwin10.

Comment: I figured it out. A conditional was erroneously evaluating to false because of which the target triple for simulator was not being picked up. "i386-apple-darwin9" works for my machine. Thanks.